# How to map JSON data graphically on a Google Map?

Tags: json, api, google-maps

I want to use the Citybik.es API (http://api.citybik.es/) to map station data (Station Name/Bikes available/Free stands) on a Google Map using the **Google Maps JavaScript API v3**.

How do I go about actually putting this data on the map? The JSON data feed gives latitude and longitude information so it comes back like this:

0: {bikes:2, name:Fenian Street, idx:0, lat:53341428, timestamp:2014-09-23T19:06:05.152Z, lng:-6246720,…}

1: {bikes:0, name:City Quay, idx:1, lat:53346637, timestamp:2014-09-23T19:06:05.864Z, lng:-6246154, id:1,…}

2: {bikes:3, name:Fitzwilliam Square East, idx:2, lat:53335211, timestamp:2014-09-23T19:06:06.915Z,…}

**These are the bits of data:**

- bikes: 6
- free: 34
- id: 82
- idx: 82
- lat: 53339983
- lng: -6295594
- name: "St. James Hospital (Central)"
- number: 81
- timestamp: "2014-09-23T19:09:25.719Z"

I'd like to map all the different station according to their coordinates on the map and show the number'bikes' and 'free' stands along with the station name.

Thank you sincerely.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. If you provide more detailed information like code and data, people are more likely to help you.

Comment: Thanks Stigandr, added some extra info.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the google maps API that you are using (Javascript or Android).

If you have a list of lat/lng points, then you can easily draw customized markers.

For further details, check the documentation:

Android:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker
Javascript:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: Thanks Amine, I added the API: Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Comment: Ok, it's very easy to draw customized markers. Google has an excellent documentation for that [link] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=FR#icons)

Comment: The biggest problem I'll probably have is actually converting the JSON data to text and affixing it to the markers.